# Ruby Model won't update on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

So rails told me that it had a problem with line 7 of this code:

```
6. scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
7. scope :invisible, lambda { where (:visible => false) }
8. scope :sorted, lambda { order("sections.position ASC") }
9. scope :newest_first, lambda { order("sections.created_at DESC") }
```

So to solve it, I removed the space between `{ where (:visible => false) }` to make it `{ where(:visible => false) }`

Assuming this to be the issue, I restarted my server, but the changes weren't recognised, and it still comes up with the same error message. I have tried the following ways to get it to update:

1. Close the server and restart it
2. Restart my computer
3. Comment out the problematic code, restart server and then close server and uncomment the problematic code
4. Comment out all the scopes, then same as step 3.

None of these have worked! It still thinks that my code reads `{ where (:visible => false) }`

...Unless there are any other things wrong with this code, can anyone suggest anything which might help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the model and the validations/scopes?

Comment: when you say "server", are you just referring to your local development server (i.e., `rails s`)?

Comment: Any chance you're using a virtual machine (e.g Virtual Box / Vagrant) to run the local rails server?

Comment: Try changing all the scopes to this format `scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true) }`

Comment: What's the error you're getting exactly? Can you post the error stack trace?